# Checkbox is not retaining its state while using ViewBag in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using ViewBag to store the state of checkbox. It is always showing false. When I remove `value="isCurrentFilter"`then It is showing enabled when I check the checkbox.

Can anyone guide me where I am going wrong?

Please advise me.

Controller

```
Public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool searchText, bool currentFilter, int? page)
    {

            int selectedPage = page ?? 1;
            int bypassCount = (selectedPage - 1) * _pagingOptions.PageSize;

            if (searchText != false)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchText = currentFilter;

            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchText;

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">

             @{ bool isCurrentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter; }

              <input type="checkbox" asp-for="searchText" value="isCurrentFilter" class="form-control" /> 

         <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
         </div>                
        </form>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th>Message Id</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Resent</th>
                <th>Resent Date</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.Items.TotalItemCount > 0)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Model.Items.ToList())
                {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageId)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resentString)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resentDateString)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => createdDateString)</td>
                    </tr>

                }
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `always showing false` where?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, In controller,`bool searchText` always returns false.But as mentioned in my question, If i remove`value="isCurrentFilter"` from `<input type="checkbox" asp-for="searchText" value="isCurrentFilter" class="form-control" /> `. then it will returns true when checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using ViewBag to store the state of checkbox. It is always showing false.

If you check the source code of checkbox in browser, you would find that it might be rendered as below, and the **value** property of checkbox is **`false`**, so you always get **`false`** even if you checked it and submit the form.

[image]

> When I remove `value="@isCurrentFilter"` then It is showing enabled when I check the checkbox.

Without explicitly set **value** property for your checkbox `<input type="checkbox" asp-for="searchText" class="form-control"/>`, the value property would be **`true`**.

[image]

And the rendered HTML as above will also include two fields (checkbox and hidden) for the `searchText` property. If the checkbox is checked, the posted value will be `searchText=true&searchText=false`. The model binder will correctly extract true from the value. Otherwise it will be false. SO as you said, removing `value="@isCurrentFilter"` will work.

Comment: And you can find more information about usage of checkbox in form in this article: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But pagination doesn’t work then. It will loose the state and also return more results.

Comment: In this thread, we discuss about "bool searchText always returns false" with using checkbox. For pagination not working issue, you can create and post a new thread for further discussion.

Comment: Can you please have a look into this one. I am struggling hard to fix this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984038/maintain-the-state-of-dropdown-while-moving-to-second-page-in-pagination

Answer (score 0):

You may use @ViewBag.CurrentFilter instead

Like this

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="searchText" value="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: How do you call the ´Index´ method?

Comment: If you see the code, I have search button. When I click on that button, it hits the index method under controller.